# Remove unrecognised staticContent mimeMap entries

Tags: iis, static-content, mime-type

On a default installation of IIS there are approximately 350 `<mimeMap />` elements specified in the `<staticContent>` section. Some file extensions seem alien to me e.g. `.sv4cpio`, `.cpio`, `.onetoc2`.

I was wondering if it would be worth removing file extensions that I know I will never be serving? Is there a benefit to doing so?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and it's recommended as a defence-in-depth security measure.

If IIS doesn't have an extension defined, the staticfilehandler won't serve it (it'll 404 instead).

Comment: Could you provide a reference? I don't really see why it would enhance security.

Comment: IIS' static file handler won't serve file types not on the list. So even if a file gets dropped onto the web server, it won't be servable.

Comment: I meant a reference to the person/company who recommends this measure.